# What is the correct URL to reach my Web API endpoint is asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, url, fetch-api

I'm working with an API in asp.net and I am trying to fetch it from my JavaScript file, but I think there is something wrong with my URL. This is my controller and the method that I want to reach:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("get-user-by-id")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser(string email, string 
                                                          password)
{
    var result = await _userService.GetUser(email, password);

    if (result == null) return NotFound();

    return Ok(result);
}
}
```

And this is the fetch function in my js file:

```js
fetch('https://"mylocalhost"/api/User/get-user-by-id', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('HTTP error! Status: ' + response.status);
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (data) {
        console.log('Login success:', data);
        window.location.href = 'profile.html';
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('Login error:', error.message);
        if (error.message.includes('401')) {
          console.log('Incorrect username or password');
        } else {
          console.log('An error occurred during login');
        }
      });
```

"my-local-host" is different from what I wrote here.

Comment: Don't use `>` for code - that's for block-quotes of prose text.

Comment: `/api/User/get-user-by-id` <-- You need to decide if you're going to follow the RPC style - or a RESTful-ish style - right now you're copying the _worst_ parts of both...

Comment: Also, it's 2023... you should use `async`/`await` with `try{}catch(e){}` in JS instead of `.then().catch()`.

Comment: Isn't it the issue with the method? I see you have HttpGet in your API and you are using POST method in your JS code. Secondly, I assume you have local trusted certificates for your app to run on "https" because usually we run localhost on "http".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the  method: 'POST' in your js function to  method: 'GET'